# Run-Time Error 438: Deleting Outlook Appointments from Excel

Tags: excel, outlook, runtime-error, vba

I have the following code written to delete all appointments from a subfolder of the Outlook Calendar. I have struggled trying to find the right way to call this subfolder in the code and am now stumped. It now seems to be able to call the correct folder but is unable to proceed with deleting the appointments. I tested this code on the default Calendar successfully before trying to direct it towards the subfolder.

I have commented out the line of code below where I am receiving run-time error 438: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

I would appreciate anyone being able to let me know what I need to change to resolve this issue.

```
Public Sub DeleteAppt()

Dim olApp As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Object 'Outlook.Namespace
Dim olAptItemFolder As Object 'Outlook.Folder
Dim olAptItem As Object 'Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim i As Long

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNS = olApp.Session
    Set olAptItemFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("TestCal").Items

    ''''For i = olAptItemFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set olAptItem = olAptItemFolder.Items(i)
        If olAptItem.Subject Like "***" Then
            olAptItem.Delete
        End If
    Next i

    Set olAptItem = Nothing
    Set olAptItemFolder = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You are mixing up the folder and the items in the folder. Change Set olAptItemFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("TestCal").Items to Set olAptItemFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders("TestCal")

Comment: If that is the answer you can ease the burden on the close vote queue by deleting the question.

Comment: Making the change you suggested did not solve the error.

Comment: There is a second less obvious problem as olAptItemFolder should be a folder. I do not know how adding .Items to the end of that line worked with your default calendar. Here for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/24141643/1571407 where items are not involved until the For loop.

Comment: Do you see a way to change this code in order to delete all the appointments in the "TestCal" folder?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the line

```
For i = olAptItemFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step - 1
```

to

```
For i = olAptItemFolder.Count To 1 Step - 1
```

Comment: This has solved run-time error 438 but now the same line returns run-time error 462: the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable. Do I need to ask this as a new question?

Comment: Yes, please ask a new question and indicate which line of your code raises that exception.